# AngularJS: Preventing addClass on page load in directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that adds a class for CSS animation, then removes said class. The problem is the directive executes the animation on load. The animation is supposed to occur only on button click. How do I prevent the animation from starting on page load?

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ganet/3/edit)

Directive:

```
app.directive('spinMe', function() {
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.spinMe, function() {
      elem.addClass('spin');
      setTimeout(function() {
        elem.removeClass('spin');
      }, 500);
    });
  };
});
```

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.toggleSpin = false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="" ng-click="toggleSpin = !toggleSpin">Start spin</a>
<div spin-me="toggleSpin">Spin me!</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On initialization - newVal == oldVal == null.
Prevent the watch to run without change:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.spinMe, function(newVal,oldVal) {
 if (newVal === oldVal) return;   //first check for change
```